# Lightroom 6 Images are showing distorted In Develop mode

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-6

I am new to Lightroom. I recently updated my Lightroom version from 5 to 6. Now I when open a image in develop mode it is being shown as distorted. Don't know which setting to turn on or off.

[image]

Comment: This seems like a graphic card issue. I'm using LR5, so I don't know for sure if they've updated the settings. You can check Preferences/Interface and see if there are any settings related to acceleration or video card, and if so try toggling them.

Comment: Also, have you tried resetting all the edits? Just in case some filters have been applied inadvertently

Comment: I have not edited the photo. Just opened in Develop mode. However, also when I switch to before/after image the before image is showing perfectly well but incase of after image the picture is being displayed as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Lightroom Preferences   [Ctrl+,]
Select the [Performance] Tab
Remove a check-mark from the option-  [  ] Use Graphics Processor,
Re-start Lightroom.

Comment: +1 for most probably correct answer, but could use a bit more prose.