# Lightroom blacks display as blue in develop mode

Tags: lightroom

In Lightroom in "Develop" mode, blacks have started displaying as blue pixels. They weren't like this before. In "Library" mode they display correctly.

[image: blacks in Lightroom develop mode]

Edit: whites also display as red pixels.

[image: whites displaying as red pixels]

This is on a Mac Studio (M1 Max)

[This question and answer is similar](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/91705/5012), but changing the graphics processor settings did not work for me. I have tried all 3 of these settings, and restarted Lightroom after each setting change. Also restarted the computer, but it still has this issue.

[image: Lightroom graphics processor settings]

Comment: I figured it out, idk if I should delete this question or not.

Comment: No, writing your solution as an answer was the right way to do it. Thanks! Also, it's okay to mark your own answer as the "accepted answer". If it's what answered your question best, then it's the accepted answer. =)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well after figuring out that the whites also displayed as red pixels, I was able to search more effectively for an answer and found this:

> It's more than likely just the clipping indicators are switched on. Press "J" to turn them off if you don't want to see where the image is clipped.

[Source](https://community.adobe.com/t5/lightroom-classic-discussions/in-lightroom-5-red-and-blue-marks-in-my-photo-s-whilst-in-the-develop-window-how-do-you-fix-it/m-p/5220320)

Answer (score 12):

Another way to switch on/off the clipping view: in Development module click on the triangles on top left and right of the histogram[image].